# Parameterized Maybe monad

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I'm making a mess with Monad, ReaderT, ... to perform a "simple?" behavior.

I want to intersperse a test function into `Maybe` transformation (`Maybe` or another personalized monad).

Exactly, I want avoid `t` calls, creating some kind of monad (monad, I think) on

```
doCalculus :: (Int -> Bool) -> Int -> Maybe Int
doCalculus f a = do
  b <- t $ a + 1
  c <- t $ 2 * b
  d <- t $ a + b + c
  return d
  where t = if f n then Just n else Nothing
```

example

```
test :: Int -> Bool
test n = not (n `elem` [3, 7, 9])

*Main> doCalculus test 2
Nothing
*Main> doCalculus test 3
Just 15
*Main>
```

I'm trying to do some monad like `ReaderT` to perform some like

```
runMaybeTest doCalculus test
```

to use as

```
doCalculus :: Int -> Maybe' Int
doCalculus a = do
  b <- a + 1
  c <- 2 * b
  d <- a + b + c
  return d

perform = runMaybe' doCalculus test
```

but I can't.

(Of course, `Int` type would be generic into monad)

Thank you for any tip!

**=== UPDATE 1 ===**

I can do it! :) ... but isn't practical (I think) :(

I had adapted a fantastic [Eric Kidd post](http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2007/03/15/data-set-monad-haskell-macros)

```
import Prelude hiding (Just, Nothing, return, (>>=))

class Tester a where
  test :: a -> Bool
  test _ = True

data MMaybe a = Nothing | Just a deriving (Eq, Show)

class Monad1 m a where
  return :: a -> m a
  fail :: String -> m a

class (Monad1 m a, Monad1 m b) => Monad2 m a b where
  (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b

instance (Tester a) => Monad1 MMaybe a where
  return = Just
  fail _ = Nothing

instance (Tester a, Tester b) => Monad2 MMaybe a b where
  Nothing >>= _ = Nothing
  (Just x) >>= f = if test x then f x else Nothing

instance Tester Int where
  test n = not $ n `mod` 2 == 0 && n `mod` 3 == 0

test1 :: Int -> MMaybe Int
test1 n =
  return n >>= \a ->
  return (a + 3) >>= \b ->
  return (a + b)

test2 = map test1 [1..20]
```

possible (important) problems are:

1. is a usable monad?
2. where is do notation?
3. only works defining test function into a unique type (new testing functions require new types)

but I can wrap test function into pseudo-monad... (it's something)

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what you are trying to do(but that's not necessarily your fault). If you want to write functions with the added context of "Maybe" use the Maybe monad and chain functions using the bind >>= operator?

Comment: If that sounds like what you are trying to do, I will submit a complete answer and try to help.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to get rid of the `t` in any non-trivial way.  How would you lift expressions into the monad, and how would you delimit where the tests should be performed?

Comment: It seems to me that you are thinking about Haskell the wrong way, neglecting its laziness.

Comment: Yes @JohnL, that's question, if I write "test" function (statically, "constantically", inline, ...) into `Maybe` monad has no problem. How parametrize that test function? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you want to (a) sequence some transformations and (b) short-circuit predicate failure at various stages. This whole process is parametric over the "contained" type (which is Int here) and the predicate.

Let's dive in.

### I

The primary effect we're controlling here is failure, so `Maybe` is a great place to start. It's `Monad` instance lets us compose various `Maybe`-producing computations.

```
-- some pure computations
f, g, h :: a -> a

-- ... lifted and sequenced!
may :: a -> Maybe a
may = (return . f) >=> (return . g) >=> (return . h)
```

This is a very ceremonial way of writing `(h . g . f)` since we're just using completely general "monadic" (really, `Kleisli`) composition and no special effects.

### II.

Given a predicate `p :: a -> Bool`, we can start to fail. The first way to do this would be to use `Maybe`'s `MonadPlus` instance and `guard :: MonadPlus m => Bool -> m ()`.

```
\a -> do x <- return (f a)
         guard (p x)
         y <- return (g x)
         guard (p y)
         z <- return (h y)
         guard (p z)
         return z
```

But we've obviously got a fairly repeated pattern going on here---at every "composition boundary" of pure functions we perform our predicate and maybe fail. This is a strong commingling of `Reader`-like and `Maybe`-like effects just like you thought, but it doesn't have quite the same `Monad`ic semantics as either of those or their stack. Can we capture it some other way?

### III.

Well, let's try wrapping them up.

```
newtype OurMonad a = OM { getOM :: MaybeT (Reader (a -> Bool)) a }
```

Now `OurMonad` is a `newtype` around the monad transformer stack including `Reader` and `Maybe`. We'll be able to take advantage of that in order to write a highly general "run" function, `runOurMonad :: (a -> Bool) -> OurMonad a -> Maybe a`.

Or, rather, it sort of feels like we could, right? I want to argue that we can't, actually. The reason is that in order to write a `Monad` instance we have to have a `Functor` instance* which means that given any function mapping `a -> b` we need to be able to map `OM a -> OM b`. The problem is that we don't generally know how to generalize our predicate! I know no way to write a function `(a -> b) -> (a -> Bool) -> b -> Bool` unless we also have a function `b -> a`**.

So we're stuck trying to generalize this to a `Monad`. I don't think it is one.

### IV.

But your example didn't actually need the full generality of Monad—we know all of our pure transformations are `Endo`, i.e. of type `a -> a`. That's one way our single predicate could be sufficient! We can take advantage of the type homogeneity to write a list of our `Endo`s as `[a -> a]`. So let's just define what we need a little more directly as a `fold` over that list:

```
stepGuarded :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> [a -> a] -> Maybe a
stepGuarded pred = foldM $ \a f -> mfilter pred (return $ f a)

stepGuarded (`elem` [3, 7, 9]) 3 [ (+1), (*2) ] 
-- Nothing

stepGuarded (`elem` [4, 8, 9]) 3 [ (+1), (*2) ]
-- Just 8
```

* n.b. Not technically true, but theoretically and practically if we can't write a `Functor` instance then we'll get stuck writing a `Monad` instance, too.

** Technically, this is still a categorical `Functor`, it's just contravariant whereas `Functor` and `Monad` assume the functor is covariant. We can generalize all of this to have functors-on-isomorphisms, Edward Kmett calls these `ExFunctor`s I think and you get to define `xmap :: (a -> b) -> (b -> a) -> f a -> f b` instead, which is nice.

Comment: This isn't sufficient for the example given in the question.  The pure transformations are not all `Endo`, in particular `d <- a + b + c` is not.  If you try to split that expression, then the predicate will be applied to each of the partial sums, which will probably be wrong.  Without knowing more about the problem, I suspect the Maybe-monad+guard solution may be the most appropriate.

Comment: @tel, thank you, I need some time to read your answer (I'm a haskeller tortoise)

Comment: @JohnL Oh! I missed that! Endo totally isn't correct then, you'd need something more like `newtype Step a = a -> (a, Step a)` perhaps. My primary intent was to show that if you fix the predicate then you can't form a simple Monad, but my `Endo` example is clearly oversimplified.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is use "let" in your do blocks.

```
doCalculus :: Int -> Maybe Int
doCalculus a = do
  let b = a + 1
  let c = 2 * b
  let d = a + b + c
  return d
```

or

```
doCalculus :: Int -> Maybe Int
doCalculus a = Just d where
  b = a + 1
  c = 2 * b
  d = a + b + c
```

and skip the do notation all together.

Comment: It looks like I'm missing the question here. I may just delete this answer if its totally wrong.

Comment: :) yes @MFlamer your answer is totally wrong but thank you, I was not very well explained (probably)